# AngularJS $http call fails due to Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: angularjs, cors, access-control

I was using `withCredentials: true` on my `$http` call to send session ID in request headers.

But I was facing:

> "the value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response
>   must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The
>   credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute."

So I changed my CORS Filter on server side to:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080/");
```

Now I am getting this error:

> "The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   'http://localhost:8080' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
>   Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Can anyone please tell me the solution?

Comment: You can echo the value of the Origin request header back to Access-Control-Allow-Origin:

`response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));`

Answer (score -1):

Try using this snippet:

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Comment: As I mentioned in problem description,

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); is throwing 

"the value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute." error.